# foundation/sass: external stylesheet for media queries replicates styles

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I want to use the sass version of foundation.

However, I also want to use external stylesheets for different screen-widths.

If, within my primary sass file, I import stylesheet within a media query, then the imported file does not have access to the foundation mixins.

However, if I import the mixins into the imported sass file, then the resulting css file replicates large amounts of the foundation styles.

How do import an external sass file that can access the foundation mixins without replicating code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one import only variables and mixins from Scss stylehsheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408324/how-can-one-import-only-variables-and-mixins-from-scss-stylehsheets)

Answer (score 0):

I like to reference my external stylesheet(s) at the bottom of `foundation.scss`:

```
// Custom Styles
@import
  "foundation/custom/small-layout",
  "foundation/custom/medium-layout",
  "foundation/custom/large-layout";
```

Note that if you do it this way, the imported sheets need to be somewhere within the `foundation` folder.

Your imported stylesheets will inherit all of the Sass goodies that were imported before it, including the media query breakpoint variables from `_variables.scss`.  Then, within each breakpoint-specific stylesheet, just wrap the whole thing in a media query using the appropriate variable:

```
@media #{$medium} {
  // styles
}
```

Hope this helps.