# Can I avoid duplicated css with Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

Im using ZF4 and I recently noted how big my css files are. On one page in particular I have 10 lines of sass, that uses the grid mixins, so I "optimized" my imports, and got to this

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation/components/global"; // *always required
@import "foundation/components/grid";

.tag-list-filter {
    @include grid-row('nest-collapse');

    .sub-nav {
        @include grid-column(6);
        margin: 0;
    }
    .date-in-filter {
        @include grid-column(4,true);
        label {
            display: inline;
        }
        input[type="text"] {
            display: inline;
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
}
```

The two imports gives me an overhead of 700 lines of CSS!!!. And Im more than glad to add those 700 lines in my app.css, given that I have lots of pages that uses the grid system, but why should I have that much duplicated css in all my pages?

Is there a way I can avoid that?

Comment: What exactly is duplicated?

Comment: The css produced by import "foundation/components/global"; (around 125 lines) and import "foundation/components/grid"; (around 600 lines). The problem is that I need to include those in most of my pages, because sass needs to know about the variables and mixins, which is fine, but in this repeated css there are also stuff like default rules for the body tag, now, I have normalize.css for that, so im guessing this is duplicated without need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one import only variables and mixins from Scss stylehsheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408324/how-can-one-import-only-variables-and-mixins-from-scss-stylehsheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cimmanon advice was right, and adding this solved my problem:

```
@import "settings";
$include-html-grid-classes: false;
$include-html-classes: false;
$include-print-styles: false;

@import "foundation/components/global"; // *always required
@import "foundation/components/grid";
```

Every component probably haves it's own variable to control whether to print styles or not.

By the way, Zurbs documentation could use a "Performance tips" section and include this tip in it. And also the don't include foundation as a whole in each page.