# Removing unused Foundation grid classes from SASS

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I'm a bit new to Foundation and SCSS. I'm trying out the grid Mixin in the example like so:

```
/* Each individual part that can be added in */
@import "foundation/components/global";
@import "foundation/components/grid";
// @import "foundation/components/visibility";
@import "foundation/components/block-grid";

#masthead { @include grid-row; @include panel;
  & > hgroup { @include grid-column(4); }
  & > section { @include grid-column(8); }
}
```

The problem is the generated CSS has the masthead, hgroup, section classes as expected, but there's also all the usual .small-1, .large-2 grid classes etc.

Is there a way to tell SASS not to generate these "extra" classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one import only variables and mixins from Scss stylehsheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408324/how-can-one-import-only-variables-and-mixins-from-scss-stylehsheets)

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer in: [How can one import only variables and mixins from Scss stylehsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408324/how-can-one-import-only-variables-and-mixins-from-scss-stylehsheets)

Basically look for "$include-html*" in foundation/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss, set to false, and that should turn off the "extra" classes.