# Foundation 5 Default SCSS - Orbit

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I have set up foundation 5 using bower and trying to config orbit.

Any ideas on how to use the obit scss import without pulling in all the unneeded sass. All I want is the bullet css and positioning. Yes I could copy it and create an override. But I don't see why this has to be done.

I see the following settings:

```
// Orbit

// $include-html-orbit-classes: $include-html-classes;

// We use these to control the caption styles
// $orbit-container-bg: none;
// $orbit-caption-bg: rgba(51,51,51, 0.8);
// $orbit-caption-font-color: #fff;
// $orbit-caption-font-size: rem-calc(14);
// $orbit-caption-position: "bottom"; // Supported values: "bottom", "under"
// $orbit-caption-padding: rem-calc(10 14);
// $orbit-caption-height: auto;

// We use these to control the left/right nav styles
// $orbit-nav-bg: none;
// $orbit-nav-bg-hover: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
// $orbit-nav-arrow-color: #fff;
// $orbit-nav-arrow-color-hover: #fff;

// We use these to control the timer styles
// $orbit-timer-bg: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
// $orbit-timer-show-progress-bar: true;

// We use these to control the bullet nav styles
// $orbit-bullet-nav-color: #ccc;
// $orbit-bullet-nav-color-active: #999;
// $orbit-bullet-radius: rem-calc(9);

// We use these to controls the style of slide numbers
// $orbit-slide-number-bg: rgba(0,0,0,0);
// $orbit-slide-number-font-color: #fff;
// $orbit-slide-number-padding: rem-calc(5);

// Graceful Loading Wrapper and preloader
// $wrapper-class: "slideshow-wrapper";
// $preloader-class: "preloader";
```

I have set up the controls using the inline data attribute, which works fine. However the unneeded scss from foundation is destroying my template. Which is causing me to use many overrides?

Also is there any explanation for this:

```
// $include-html-orbit-classes: $include-html-classes;
```

I am sure someone else has been in my position with the latet framework from zurb.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one import only variables and mixins from Scss stylehsheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408324/how-can-one-import-only-variables-and-mixins-from-scss-stylehsheets)

Comment: I can see what you mean, however I am referring to specific block of an imported file. In this case I have targeted orbit. But I am unable to focus on the bullet point section of this scss