# How to avoid duplication of styles in SCSS?

Tags: sass

I want to have one `.scss` file with some varibles for all the rest `.scss` files. But if I do so its `.scss` styles are duplicated in all my `.scss` files:

**global.scss** - my global variables and styles file

```
$white: #FFF;
$black: #000;
$bg_red: red;

.mt30 {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

**header.scss** - I want to use global vars and styles in this file.

```
@include "global"

.foo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    backgrounnd-color: $bg_red;
}
```

**main.scss** - I want to use global vars and styles in this file too.

```
@include "global"

.boo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    backgrounnd-color: $white;
}
```

But each final `.css` file has styles from **global.scss**. So I have several `.mt30` styles on my page. How to avoid it?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here.  You don't want duplicate information, but you understand how imports work.  If you want to import a file multiple times, don't put code in it that you don't want duplicated.

Comment: **"each final .css file"** - Why do you have more than one CSS file?  You should only have one complied file which is created from a single 'main' SCSS file after importing all of the sub-SCSS files - http://www.sitepoint.com/architecture-sass-project/

Comment: @cimmanon, Hey, it is an examle. The real thing is that SCSS, Compass, Assetic are not good enough. If I need a variable from one main file in some other files, I have to import that main file in each other file. So for example with scss bootstap I have all bootstrap's styles duplicated in every file on the page when I need bootstrap's vars in my each file. How to avoid it? Why these tools include styles again if styles are already imported once somewhere?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408324/how-can-one-import-only-variables-and-mixins-from-scss-stylehsheets

Comment: @Paulie_D there are some suggestions of multiple css files per page, for example, delivering an [above the fold file](https://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/), and / or a global file and a page specific file in order to optimise file sizes

Answer (score 21):

It seems that the issue isn't the duplication of styles, but the duplication of libraries, or configuration files. For that, all it takes is to just structure your code a little differently. Start by making your `global.scss` file a partial by changing its name (as well as all the other pieces) to start with an underscore, `_global.scss`. Then, create a manifest file, like `app.scss`. Inside there, import `_global.scss` and whatever other files you need. Those other files will now have access to everything that `app.scss` has access to:

**_global.scss**

```
$white: #FFF;
$black: #000;
$bg_red: red;
```

**_header.scss**

```
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: $bg_red;
}
```

**_main.scss**

```
.mt30 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.boo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: $white;
}
```

**app.scss**

```
// Import libraries and config; adding compass as an example
@import "global";
@import "compass/css3";

// Actual selectors
@import "header";
@import "main";
```

Because you're importing global before header and main, the latter two will have access to whatever's in the former. Also to note is that I moved the one declared style, `.mt30`, out from global into the main partial, only to make sure no styles were being declared in the global config file.

Comment: why do you have to move `.mt30` out from `_global.scss`?

Answer (score 1):

For example: Foundation framework has `app.scss` file. It first imports `settings` then `foundation`. After this you can add your app specific rules.

`settings` contains settings for all Foundation components and doesn't  inflate resulting css. `foundation` file contains set of separated imports for the individual components like grid, buttons etc. Those components are configured by the previously imported `settings` file.  To reduce css file size you can remove imports for the unnecessary components.

*Actually, to make it more accessible, user removes `foundation` import and replace it with individual imports of the components that are commented out be the default.*

Answer (score 0):

There's a thing that you can use for that, it's import-once:

https://rubygems.org/gems/compass-import-once

Usage

To use with the Sass command line:

```
sass -r 'compass/import-once/activate' ...
```

To enable in non-compass environments:

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
```

You can read more information on this here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/compass-import-once/1.0.5/frames

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you learn the @use technique, it will make things easier for you, and stop using the @import itself, here is a helpful resource
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR-a8upNjJ0

Comment: Code examples would be useful: e.g. how/where to use @use

Comment: please check the video @MiheyEgoroff