# Import scss file but do not render its contains

Tags: sass

I have a SCSS file that contains CSS. I want to extend those classes yet I don't want to render those on my main file (refer below).

**File structure:**

```
_vars.scss
main.scss
```

**main.scss**

```
@import 'vars';
//extend margin class
body{
    margin: @extend .m10;
}
```

**In my _vars.scss**

```
.m10{margin:10px;}
.p10{padding:10px;}
```

If the main SCSS is compiled, it will be compiled to:

**main.css**

```
.m10{margin:10px;} /* <-- i dont want to see this in my compiled scss --> */
.p10{padding:10px;} /* <-- i dont want to see this in my compiled scss --> */
body{
    margin: 10px;  /* <-- but still extent from the .m10 class of _vars.scss --> */
}
```

Any ideas to not display those classes from the `_vars.scss` yet still extending those classes in the `main.scss`? Is there a way to do that with SASS?

Comment: Have you tried `@import '_vars';` ?

Comment: yes but still it display on the compiled main.scss

Comment: main.scss and _vars.scss both in same folder ?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18408513/2405101) seems to indicate that `import` is an "all-or-nothing" with `scss`

Answer (score 3):

The way to go is to use placeholders instead of classes:

`_vars.scss`:

```
%m10 {
  margin:10px;
}
%p10 { 
  padding:10px;
}
```

`main.scss`

```
@import 'vars';
body {
  @extend %m10; 
}
```

Which produces, compiled:

```
body{
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Placeholders only produce CSS if they are used. Better, they'll concatenate all selectors using them, to avoid duplicate contents:

```
body {
  @extend %m10;
  background: red;
}
main > article {
  @extend %m10;
}
```

Will outputs:

```
body, main > article {
  margin: 10px;
}
body {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I do forget about the placeholders all the time !

Answer (score 2):

The output you get is exactly what it's supposed to be.

If you don't want to have:

```
.m10{margin:10px;} /* <-- i dont want to see this in my compiled scss --> */
.p10{padding:10px;} /* <-- i dont want to see this in my compiled scss --> 
*/
body{
margin: 10px;  /* <-- but still extent from the .m10 class of _vars.scss --> 
*/
```

}

You shouldn't use a class and an `@extend` but a mixin and an `@include`

Here is what you could do:

```
@mixin m10 {
  margin: 10px;
}

body{
  @include m10;
}
```

It would even be better to add a variable :

```
@mixin myMargin($size) {
  margin: #{$size}px;
}

.input {
   @include myMargin(10);
}
```

This way, you can choose your margin size.